# How does the typename keyword work?

Tags: c++, typename

For my advance data structure class i am trying to figure out how typename works

```
/** Return an iterator pointing past the last item in the BST.
 */
 iterator end() const {
 return typename BST<Data>::iterator(nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Do you understand *anything* about it, and if so, what?

Comment: This is a complex question and involves a lot of knowledge about compiler theory, qualified vs unqualified naming, and dependent vs non-dependent names. Here's a link that does a decent job of explaining it, but by no means a perfect explanation: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html

Comment: @scottHunter sorry I come from java

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much you understand but, a very gross generalization for why typename is used in that return statement is the following: Before a qualified dependent type, you must use typename.
C++ has a parsing rule stating qualified dependent names will be parsed as non-types even if it results in a syntax error. So, if there was a variable called nc in scope, the example would be legal without the use of typename, however, it would be interpreted as multiplication. This would ultimately lead to an error because you can't multiply something by a type (not considering operator overloading which introduces yet more complexity).By using typename, you are telling/enforcing the compiler to treat the name that follows as a type.
**Try this code and remove typename you should get a compiler error**

```
class Foo {
 public:
   class NestedType {
      public:
   };
};


template <typename T>
struct MyStruct {
  typename T::NestedType * nt; // Declare a pointer to T's NestedType
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 struct MyStruct<Foo> myStruct;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to put it in easier terms?